# Look across multiple .ppt(x) files and find similar slides or group slides by similarity

Tags: powerpoint

I'm a sales engineer and do presentations. I must have some 1000+ powerpoint decks. I want some software that **searches my computer for all ppt(x) files and goes through all of the slides and indexes them somehow.** (for this part there are many tools that do this - many focusing on text search).

Here's the piece I'm not finding. I want to be able to **group by slide similarity.** So, if I have a slide where this one slide is the same across 20 different PPTs, but on one deck I updated the text to something I want to use for the next time, it's impossible to find it. Therefore, if it could show me visual representations of the slides and show me that there are 60 slides that are "similar" and show me the 60 versions in a grid, I could quickly pick the one I want, vs opening each deck one by one.

Is there any software like this?

Comment: Great question. I wonder if 7.5 years later we have a good answer for you...

Answer (score 1):

After the recommendation of @Izzy I decide to give a better illustrate answer and come up with this [Slide Manager](http://slidemanager.biz/product/) that offeres a central, searchable library and I am quoting what they are describing on the page:

- Find and Consolidate Duplicate Slides Quickly and Easily: you can
  select a slide, and find all other slides in your library that are
  similar,

  - Update a Slide Everywhere it Exists.

I guess this is the main point you looking for within the software.